# How to get all child branches which were branched of some parent one

Tags: git

Let's say I have `ParentBranch` and a lot of branches were branched of `ParentBranch` during a month.
After rebasing of parent branch I need to rebase all the child branches as well, but can't find out how can I get all them.
Currently I'm just looking through history, but is there some command to get that data at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky thing to do because new branches can be created at any point in any repository from any commit in any given branch's history.

But what you can do is look at all the branches and look for their relationships, like this:

```
git branch -a 
or
git show-ref --heads
```

If you look at [git branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) doc, you will find the `--contains` flag, so you can also use this:

```
git branch --contains <branch>
```

where `<branch>` is you parent branch name.